# fetch data in react native from mlab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, backend, mlab

I am trying to learn fetching data from the server with an `apikey`. I've created some document with this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json).
 With my document's [link](https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/ibrhmklnc/collections/kitap?apiKey=xRw1H6NNZZnyeZArU5L8oUoVcsFb6tpf), I can't list items on my code.

import React from 'react'; import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator,
    Text, View  } from 'react-native';

`export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {  
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}   }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/ibrhmklnc/collections/kitap?apiKey=xRw1H6NNZZnyeZArU5L8oUoVcsFb6tpf')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){
        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });   }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );   } }`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete response from the API

```
[
    { 
        _id: { '$oid': '5be7260efb6fc072d46759b5' },
        movies: [ 
            { id: '1', title: 'Star Wars', releaseYear: '1977' },
            { id: '2', title: 'Back to the Future', releaseYear: '1985' },
            { id: '3', title: 'The Matrix', releaseYear: '1999' },
            { id: '4', title: 'Inception', releaseYear: '2010' },
            { id: '5', title: 'Interstellar', releaseYear: '2014' } 
        ] 
    }
]
```

As you can see, the API response is an array. So, in order to take the movies' list, you should set your dataSource as following:

```
dataSource: responseJson[0].movies,
```